# Persistent Cookie Jar in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, cookies, apollo

I have created this cookie jar class which I have been using to store the cookie for my Apollo server.

```
private class MyCookieJar(): CookieJar {

    private var cookies: List<Cookie> = emptyList()

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        this.cookies = cookies
    }
    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        if (cookies != null)
            return cookies
        return emptyList()
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I reload the app I need to resign in every time which I am trying to avoid. Let me know if anyone has a solid solution to this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to store credentials these would need to be encrypted for a solution you would ship to a customer. This is not trivial to implement but people have made walkthrough guides for this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_q07P1sfcc

If you want to try something out quickly that is not safe for end-user consumption I would recommend Jetpack DataStore.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore